# kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.Rectangle' object has no attribute 'collide_widget'

Tags: python, kivy

I am new to kivy and try to creat a game where the ball would be bouncing from a movable rectangle. I saw in a pong game tutorial that collide_widget can be used to detect collision. So, I used a similar function bounce_ball() to detect collision in my case, but it doesn't work.

```
class MainWidget(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.ball_size = dp(50)

        with self.canvas:
            self.ball = Ellipse(pos = (100, 200), size = (self.ball_size, self.ball_size))
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1/60)

        self.x_rect = dp(30)

        with self.canvas:
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=(100, 150), size = (self.width*0.8, self.height*0.4))


        self.a, self.b = self.rect.pos


    def bounce_ball(self, ball):

        if self.rect.collide_widget(ball):
            print("Collision detected!")

    def update(self, dt):
        self.bounce_ball(self.ball)

        x, y = self.ball.pos
        x += self.vx
        y += self.vy
        #self.ball.pos = (x, y)
        r, z = self.ball.size

        if x > self.width - r:
            #print("x")
            #x = self.width - r
            self.vx = -self.vx
        if y > self.height - z:
            #print("y")
            y = self.height - self.ball_size
            self.vy = -self.vy

        self.ball.pos = (x, y)


    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        x, y = self.rect.size


        self.a = touch.x
        if self.a > self.width - x:
            self.a = self.width - x

        self.rect.pos = (self.a, self.b)

class GameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()


GameApp().run()
```

Can you please explain why and how ro fix that?

Comment: The `collide_widget()` is a method of `Widget` and checks for overlap between the calling `Widget` and the argument `Widget`. Neither the `Ellipse` nor the `Rectangle` are `Widgets` (they are canvas instructions), So you cannot use that method here. I suggest that you write a new method that checks for overlap between a `Rectangle` and an `Ellipse` using the attributes of those canvas instructions.

Comment: You can improve the question by giving some details what exactly does not work, maybe including some tracebacks.